# How to retain similar character encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, text-files

I have a logfile that contains the half character ½, I need to process this log file and rewrite certain lines to a new file, which contain that character.  However, when I write out the file the characters appear in notepad incorrectly.

I know this is some kind of encoding issue, and i'm not sure if it's just that the files i'm writing don't contain the correct bom or what.

I've tried reading and writing the file with all the available encoding options in the Encoding enumeration.

I'm using this code:

```
string line;

// Note i've used every version of the Encoding enumeration
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Unicode))
using (StreamWRiter sw = new StreamWriter(newfile, false, Encoding.Unicode))
{
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // process code, I do not alter the lines, they are copied verbatim
        // but i do not write every line that i read.

        sw.WriteLine(line);
    } 
}
```

When I view the original log in notepad, the half character displays correctly.  When I view the new file, it does not.  This tells me the problem is not with notepad being able to display the character, because it works in the original.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Encoding isn't an enumeration - but there are many static properties. Have you tried Encoding.Default? That and Encoding.UTF8 are the most likely options.

Comment: Is the original file in unicode?

Comment: Read the comments. I've tried them all, including default.

Comment: Jon, UTF8 doesn't do it either.  Still comes out as a weird character in notepad.

Comment: Could it be the fact that i'm using ReadLine() and storing it in a string? Could that be messing with the encoding?  Does opening a file with a certain encoding using StreamWriter create the BOM?

Comment: Try opening both files in a text editor that displays the hex values, and see if they are different.  If they are, what are the different values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was PEBKAC.

I was changing the encodings in a different part of the program that wasn't creating these files.  When I changed the correct files, using Encoding.Default, it displays correctly.

Thanks Jon and others.